# Consultation about camera Resolution in android

Tags: android

i try to retrieve camera Resolution in MegaPixels like this:

```
android.hardware.Camera cam = android.hardware.Camera.open();
android.hardware.Camera.Size size = cam.getParameters().getPictureSize();
DecimalFormat localDecimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.#");        
res = "Camera MegaPixel: " +  localDecimalFormat.format(size.width * size.height / 1000000.0D);            
cam.release();
```

but i get wrong number, and i dont know if this the front or the back camera,

How to adjust for front and back camera ?

Comment: did u mean to specify the front or back camera so that u can retrieve the supported sizes of the front/back camera?

Comment: i need to get the front and the back camera